# Database on IIS server - need to access with api in android phone via localhost

Tags: android, asp.net, iis

I had configured the IIS server on Windows 8 on same we had a database.
Already made the api in .Net Framework to access the database.

Now we had made an android app to access the module of the desktop application via app.

Api is being is used in the android app.

Now stucked in the situation, how to connect the iis server (database) via android app.

How to setup the network between the server and the tablet on which the application will be runnning.

Comment: What is the problem? If you know the local ip of the computer where your server runs on then use that ip in the android app to connect to the server. Provided your android device is in the same network.

Comment: hello sir
Thanks for the help!!
Can you let me know we have to impletment the ip in the code right?
how can we? Please let me know..